# Print to PDF with Rotativa - MVC5 with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, layout, rotativa

Trying to print my views to PDF and I am getting pdfs rendered as for mobile device. Basically, I think smallest screen is detected and css styles for mobile are used. Is there a way to fix this?

I tried to change format size and make it really big, tried to use landscape orientation, but content would just scale up and it would still show with mobile styles.

I am thinking to render a partial view to pdf and have custom css file just for pdf exports, but that seems like a lot of not necessary work

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you could be doing is using the print media type in your stylesheet. It would look something like this:

```
@media print {
    p {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Maybe you already use this media type and put it in your mobile styling? Might want to put it above any responsive input and see how that works out?